# Why async ajax request not executed when using history.back

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have this snippet:

```
functionThatMakeAsyncAjaxCall(url, data);
history.back()
```

I checked in Firebug and I don't see any Ajax call to the server. I use JQuery to make the ajax request. I also checked the Persist option in Firebug.

Comment: Show your full code please :)

Comment: Navigating away aborts all ongoing requests.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fire `history.back()` in callback once ajax request is complete.

```
functionThatMakeAsyncAjaxCall(url, data).then(function(){
  history.back();
});
```

here `functionThatMakeAsyncAjaxCall` should return a promise

Comment: My question is not how to make it work, but why my code doesn't work and you don't answer that.

Comment: this is happening because by the time your browser can send that xhr request, you are already navigated away form the current page, so the callbacks on current page are invalidated.